Global costmap is only partial, and the path planning goes straight through the global obstacles
I use the navigation-noetic-level package to perform simulation in Gazebo and use Cartographer for SLAM mode.
However, when I open Rviz, I find that the costmap is not fully displayed, and even the global planning will directly pass through obstacles.
If I replace Cartographer with AMCL and map_server, it can run normally.
I have never encountered such a situation before. May I ask if anyone is very familiar with this kind of problem?
Here my project:https://gitee.com/mmeroke/dm_ws
The param files on dm_ws/src/turn_on_robot/param
Edit:
Here are my startup files.
# start gazebo and robot model
roslaunch urdf_gazebo union.launch

# start cartographer and navigation
roslaunch turn_on_robot control.launch


Here is only global costmap. Obviously, it's only part of.

cartographer_ros configuration:
backpack_2d.lua
include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"

options = {
  map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
  trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "imu",
  published_frame = "base_footprint",
  odom_frame = "odom",
  provide_odom_frame = true,
  publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,
  use_pose_extrapolator = true,
  use_odometry = true,
  use_nav_sat = false,
  use_landmarks = false,
  num_laser_scans = 1,
  num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
  num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1,
  num_point_clouds = 0,
  lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
  submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
  pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,
  trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,
  rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,
}

MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_2d = true
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.num_accumulated_range_data = 10

-- local slam params
-- 采用非单调步骤，这可能会跳过一些局部最优解，从而加快求解速度，但可能会略微影响精度。
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.ceres_scan_matcher.ceres_solver_options.use_nonmonotonic_steps=true

-- 匹配搜索
-- TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_online_correlative_scan_matching = true

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.motion_filter.max_distance_meters = 0.2  --运动滤波更新距离   
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.motion_filter.max_angle_radians = math.rad(10.0)
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.motion_filter.max_time_seconds = 5

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.min_range = 0.1
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.max_range = 8.
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_imu_data = true --是否使用imu数据

-- 如果希望子图包含更多信息以提高局部地图的完整性，可以将该值增大。
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.submaps.num_range_data=45

-- global slam
POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes=90

-- 如果想要更精细的匹配，可以适当增加深度；如果计算资源有限或者想要更快的匹配速度，可以减小深度
-- POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.fast_correlative_scan_matcher.branch_and_bound_depth=5


-- -- 设定POSE_GRAPH约束构建中的最小分数为0.7，这意味着只有匹配分数达到0.7及以上的结果才会用于构建约束，以保证约束质量
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.min_score = 0.65
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.global_localization_min_score=0.65

return options


costmap_common_params.yaml
#机器人几何参，如果机器人是圆形，设置 robot_radius,如果是其他形状设置 footprint
robot_radius: 0.22 #圆形
# footprint: [[-0.15, -0.15], [-0.15, 0.15], [0.15, 0.15], [0.15, -0.15]] #其他形状

obstacle_range: 2.5 # 用于障碍物探测，比如: 值为 3.0，意味着检测到距离小于 3 米的障碍物时，就会引入代价地图
raytrace_range: 3 # 用于清除障碍物，比如：值为 3.5，意味着清除代价地图中 3.5 米以外的障碍物

# 默认被全局代价地图使用
#膨胀半径，扩展在碰撞区域以外的代价区域，使得机器人规划路径避开障碍物
inflation_radius: 0.10
#代价比例系数，越大则代价值越小
cost_scaling_factor: 5.0 # dafault 5.0
track_unknown_space: true
#导航包所需要的传感器
observation_sources: scan
#对传感器的坐标系和数据进行配置。这个也会用于代价地图添加和清除障碍物。例如，你可以用激光雷达传感器用于在代价地图添加障碍物，再添加kinect用于导航和清除障碍物。
scan: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}


global_costmap_params.yaml
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map #地图坐标系
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint #机器人坐标系
  # 以此实现坐标变换

  update_frequency: 1.0 #默认1.0 代价地图更新频率
  publish_frequency: 1.0 #默认1.0 代价地图的发布频率
  transform_tolerance: 0.5 #等待坐标变换发布信息的超时时间

  plugins:
    - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"} # 静态地图层 
    - {name: obstacle_layer,          type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"} # 障碍地图层
    - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"} # 膨胀地图层，用于留出足够的安全距离

local_costmap_params.yaml
local_costmap:
  global_frame: map #里程计坐标系，不要设置成odam（Extrapolation Error）
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint #机器人坐标系

  update_frequency: 4.0 # 默认10.0 代价地图更新频率
  publish_frequency: 3.0 #默认10.0 代价地图的发布频率
  transform_tolerance: 0.5 #等待坐标变换发布信息的超时时间

  #膨胀半径，扩展在碰撞区域以外的代价区域，使得机器人规划路径避开障碍物，local可以设置的比global小
  inflation_radius: 0.07
  #代价比例系数，越大则代价值越小
  cost_scaling_factor: 5.0 # default 5.0

  rolling_window: true #是否使用动态窗口，默认为false，在静态的全局地图中，地图不会变化
  width: 2 # 默认3，局部地图宽度 单位是 m
  height: 2 # 默认3，局部地图高度 单位是 m
  resolution: 0.05  # deafault 0.05 局部地图分辨率 单位是 m，一般与静态地图分辨率(map/nav.yaml)保持一致
  plugins:
    - {name: obstacle_layer,      type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer,     type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

move_base_params.yaml
shutdown_costmaps: false  #当move_base在不活动状态时,是否关掉costmap.

controller_frequency: 5.0  #向底盘控制移动话题cmd_vel发送命令的频率.
controller_patience: 3.0 # 3.0 在空间清理操作执行前,控制器花多长时间等有效控制下发
 
planner_frequency: 0.0  #全局规划操作的执行频率.如果设置为0.0,则全局规划器仅
#       在接收到新的目标点或者局部规划器报告路径堵塞时才会重新执行规划操作.
planner_patience: 3.0  # default 3.0 在空间清理操作执行前,留给规划器多长时间来找出一条有效规划.

oscillation_timeout: 3.0  #default 5.0执行修复机制前,允许振荡的时长.
oscillation_distance: 0.15  #来回运动在多大距离以上不会被认为是振荡.

# Planner selection 规划器选项
base_global_planner: "global_planner/GlobalPlanner" #指定用于move_base的全局规划器插件名称.
# base_local_planner: "base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS"
base_local_planner: "teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" # 指定用于move_base的局部规划器插件名称.
# base_local_planner: "eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" # 指定用于move_base的局部规划器插件名称.
max_planning_retries: 1  #

recovery_behavior_enabled: true  #
clearing_rotation_allowed: false  #

recovery_behaviors:  #
  # 无作用，旋转后依旧无法找到可行路径
  # - name: 'rotate_recovery'
  #   type: 'rotate_recovery/RotateRecovery'

  - name: 'conservative_reset'  #
    type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'  #
  - name: 'aggressive_reset'
    type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'
  - name: 'super_reset'
    type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'

  - name: 'move_slow_and_clear'
    type: 'move_slow_and_clear/MoveSlowAndClear'
    
# rotate_recovery:
#   sim_granularity: 0.017
#   frequency: 20.0
conservative_reset:  #
  reset_distance: 1.0  #
  #layer_names: [static_layer, obstacle_layer, inflation_layer]
  layer_names: [obstacle_layer]  #

aggressive_reset:  #
  reset_distance: 3.0  #
  #layer_names: [static_layer, obstacle_layer, inflation_layer]
  layer_names: [obstacle_layer]

super_reset:  #
  reset_distance: 5.0  #
  #layer_names: [static_layer, obstacle_layer, inflation_layer]
  layer_names: [obstacle_layer]

move_slow_and_clear:  #
  clearing_distance: 0.5  #
  limited_trans_speed: 0.1  #
  limited_rot_speed: 0.4  #
  limited_distance: 0.3  #


# # 是否是全向移动机器人
# holonomic_robot: false
# # Forward Simulation Parameters，前进模拟参数
# sim_time: 4.0 # default 0.8 ,提高此参数能有效提高运行轨迹的平滑，一般1~2
# vx_samples: 20 # default 18  在 x 方向上进行速度采样时平移部分的量
# vtheta_samples: 40 # default 20  控制速度采样中旋转部分的量,倾向于设置 vth_samples 的值大于平移部分的值
# sim_granularity: 0.05




Your links seems to be not public accessible?(403 -> forbidden)

@vermaete Sorry, I forgot to open the access permissions. It is now accessible.

Please edit your post to tell us if you intend to use cartographer in SLAM mode or in localization-only mode. What created/generated the gray "walls" in your screenshot?

You have many launch files at the gitee url. Please edit your question to tell us the exact roslaunch command lines you are using to start up.

@Mike973 Thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my question and also cartographer uses SLAM mode. I think this gray "wall" was generated by cartogrpaher.

I got the solution from this link：https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/issues/1498
I think the problem comes from the fact that the gray value set by Cartographer for the obstacle grid is too low and cannot be retained as an obstacle.
So according to the method in this link, I set the grid with a grayscale value above 65 to 100.

It would be nice for future readers if you'd briefly summarize the cause of the failiure and how you fixed it. But keep the url in your answer too.

That's good. Thanks for updating your answer.
